# Error:Error response status: 13 when calling waitForCondition

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a browser test using selenium-webdriverjs. When I call the following code snippet, I get Error:Error response: 13.

```
browser.waitForCondition('var element = document.querySelector(".selector"); var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,null); style =' + btnColor ,timeout);
```

I am waiting for a condition which I would like to get a computed css style from an element obtained from a css selector. Then the computed css style is compared to a variable called btnColor. (I know that it is also possible to do the same thing using a Webdriver JS API method called getComputedCss. However, I am interested in using waitForCondition to achieve the same purpose.)

I would like to know how to properly use waitForCondition to achieve what I want to do as said above and why the code snippet is throwing the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer to this question.I have made several javascript mistakes in the expression. The following is the code snippet I have used to solve my problem.

```
browser.waitForCondition('var element = window.document.querySelector(".selector"); var style = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("background-color"); style ="' + btnColor + '"',timeout);
```

1) In order to use document, you need to call the window object first.
2) In order to get the computed background-color, I need to use the method .getPropertyValue().
3) btnColor contains a string. Therefore I need to put a double-quotation around it for the interpreter to recognize it as a string.